How do I get a subset of data from an API when I don't know the max number of pages
This is related to a question I posted previously: How do I get all data from an API when I don't know the max number of pages.
I am pulling data using an API in Python. I can filter the response so it only returns data where a receivedDate is between a specified start and end date, but I don't know how many pages meets this condition. I wrote the code below to address this. Pieces of the code works, but it does not complete, so I end it. I think it's because it's looping through every page. Can I modify this to only loop through pages that contain a receivedDate that exists between a start date and an end date without looping through every page?
import requests
import datetime
import json

start_date = datetime.datetime(2016,10,1).isoformat() #convert to ISO-8601 to match the date format of the response
end_date = datetime.datetime(2017,9,30).isoformat()
page_size = 2000
page_number = 1

while True:

    data = f'{{"receivedDateFrom":"{start_date}", "receivedDateTo":"{end_date}", "pageSize":{page_size}, "pageNumber":{page_number}}}' # I have confirmed this formating works
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, verify= True, data=data) #leaving out url and headers because of data privacy concerns, but I have confirmed this works
    response_data = response.json()
    
    if not response_data:
        break
        
    all_data.extend(response_data)

    page_number +=1


Do you know what response_data looks like when there is no data? It's possible that although no data is in the response, response_data is still a truthy value, like {"data": []}, and that's why the loop is never exiting. You could check what an empty response looks like by picking an unreasonably large page number or filter parameters that you expect no data will match.

Depends on the API: most APIs return paginated data with metadata that tells you which page you just got, and how many total pages there are, so you can run as many API calls as you need to get all the pages. Alternatively, some APIs come with a "next set" identifier that you add to your next call to (unsurprisingly) get the next page, which you keep doing until there's no "next set" identifier. Without details on which API you're calling, or at least details on what the response looks like, there's no way for folks to give concrete answers on what to do short of "read their documentation".

@schwartz721 I tried dates that don't exist and the response.json( ) was indeed [ ]

How long are you letting the script run before interrupting it? Is it possible that there's a LOT of data, and you're interrupting the program before it can get through all the pages?

What happens if you try to visit page 9999999999999999? It could be that the API is built in such a way that it returns the last page of results instead of an empty result when you visit a page that is out of the result range.

@schwartz721 There is a lot of data, 15 TB worth. It's partly why I only want to pull a small subset based on date. I've let it run for an hour. I can pull the data by specifying a large page_size and there are about 200,000 rows (converted to pandas) of data that match the start and end date that I specify. That runs in seconds. The problem is that I need to run this repeadetly on different dates and I won't know how large the page_size is for each of those dates, so that's why I wanted to create the loop based on what is returned.

@schwartz721 This is the API error message I get with a page_num of 9999999999999999: "'$.pageNumber': ['The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.pageNumber | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 48.']}." If I run it with a page_num of 100,000,000 I get this error message from the API "{'StatusCode': 500, 'Message': 'Internal Server Error.'}"

Oh wow, I just noticed that page_num += 1 is on a different indent level, so is not inside the while loop. If that's the case in your code (and not just a type-o in the question) then the page number isn't being incremented and you're fetching the first page over and over

This is how I resolved it with help from discussion above:
start_date = datetime.datetime(2016,10,1).isoformat() #convert to ISO-8601 to match the date format of the response
end_date = datetime.datetime(2017,9,30).isoformat()
page_size = 2000
page_number = 1

all_data = []

while True:
    data = f'{{"receivedDateFrom":"{start_date}", "receivedDateTo":"{end_date}", "pageSize":{page_size}, "pageNumber":{page_number}}}'
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, verify= True, data=data)
    response_data = response.json()

    if response.json() == []:
        break
        
    all_data.extend(response_data)

    page_number +=1

